# Ionic how to push or set root to app.component.ts again?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am using some function for this i need to refresh app. So i dont know how is it possible in my mind i think i need to call app.component.ts so then my app will refresh ?

```
notify() {
    console.log("Toggled: "+ this.isToggled); 

if(this.isToggled == true){
    console.log('true');
    this.storage.set('english', true);

    (navigator as any).app.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

}

if(this.isToggled == false){
      console.log('false');
      this.storage.set('english', false);
      (navigator as any).app.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

}
}
```

As you see i try to loadUrl but its not working

Comment: Why do you need to refresh the app, what is the purpose you need to achieve the refresh for?

Answer (score 0):

Look the ionic documentation to ionic refresher : the example is this

```
<!-- Custom Refresher Content -->
<ion-content>
  <ion-refresher slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content
      pullingIcon="chevron-down-circle-outline"
      pullingText="Pull to refresh"
      refreshingSpinner="circles"
      refreshingText="Refreshing...">
    </ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>
</ion-content>
```

and in the component

```
mport { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'refresher-example',
  templateUrl: 'refresher-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['./refresher-example.css'],
})
export class RefresherExample {
  constructor() {}
   /*your refresher function*/
  doRefresh(event) {
    console.log('Begin async operation');
    /* thats to emulate a fetch api delay*/
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Async operation has ended');
      event.target.complete();
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

Comment: it refresh only the page i nee to refresh app

Comment: why do you need to refresh the app ?